# MySQL update based upon postal code

Tags: mysql, sql-update

i have a usertable which includes a field named zip (postal code)
I also have a geo table with latitude, longitude values, based upon zipcodes.

so:

```
usertable 
table_1 contains fields: zip, latitude,longitude (in last 2 fields all values are NULL)
geotable:
table_2 contains fields: zip, latitude,longitude
```

The zipcode in table_1 has this format: `1111 AA` (4 numbers, 2 letters, usually split by empty character)

The zipcode in table_2 has format: `1111` (only four numbers)

I am trying to find out how an update query should look like?

I want to update the usertable with the values from the geotable, so a search query can be done without any joins. Search queries are the most used queries on this site, The updates/checks seldom.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Terrible DB-schema. Redesign it first: duplicated data, combined field is contra even 1st Normal Form

Comment: it is, but it isn't mine. in the usertable theire is a field zip, i just added a geotable, and want to add the geo data in the same table. I only have the geo-table as duplicated data table.Their is a performance reason for not using the geotable for the search query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write

```
UPDATE table_1 SET
  latitude = (SELECT latitude FROM table_2 WHERE table_1.zip LIKE CONCAT(table_2.zip, '%')),
  longitude = (SELECT longitude FROM table_2 WHERE table_1.zip LIKE CONCAT(table_2.zip, '%'));
```

Unfortunately I don't believe there is syntax quite similar to what Colin is suggesting. You may find it more efficient to simply select the values from `table_2` first and then insert them.

Comment: I have used this solution, seems to work (values not tested yet, but the fields have been udate), but.....my original values are decimals like: 52.35993326000000000000 but the udated values are whole numbers only?

Comment: had to add (23,20) to decimal and then it worked fine! The inner join solution did not work? got 0 rows affected?

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but for developing my own mysql skills, please could you explain to me what table_1.zip LIKE CONCAT(tabel_2.zip, '%') exactly does?

Comment: `LIKE` will match text using `%` as a wildcard. Since you want to match a prefix of the zip code, `CONCAT` will add `%` to the end of the zip ensuring you find a match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `UPDATE ... JOIN` clause to join the tables and perform the update:

```
update
    usertable ut inner join geotable gt on
        ut.zip like concat(gt.zip, '%')
    set ut.latitude = gt.latitude,
        ut.longitude = gt.longitude;
```

Demo: http://www.sqlize.com/398E9CKddr

Comment: Didn't realize you could use joins in an `UPDATE`. This is definitely a better answer.

Comment: This one did not work for me, got 0 rows affected. Probably due to "on ut.zip like concat(gt.zip, '%')
" ut.zip and gt.zip have different formats, unfortunately. So i think therefore the inner join won't work because of these differences?

Comment: `ut.zip like concat(gt.zip, '%')` means the two fields match if they contain the same starting characters.  So a `ut.zip` of `1111 AA` will match a `gt.zip` of `1111` in the join because the starting characters of `ut.zip` all match the entire string of `gt.zip`, which is I believe how your spec was defined.  Did you look at the sample code I linked to?  How is your data different from the example code?

Comment: table: lp_relations_addresses` 
  `zip` varchar(10) default NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(23,20) default NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(23,20) default NULL,

) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1  ;

records like:
zip: 9641 GD
latitude: NULL
longitude: NULL

TABLE `jos_geodb` 
  `postalcode` int(5) NOT NULL default '0',
  `latitude` decimal(23,20) NOT NULL default '0.00000000000000000000',
  `longitude` decimal(23,20) NOT NULL default '0.00000000000000000000'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

records like:
postalcode: 1000
latitude: 52.35402048000000000000
longitude:4.91704430000000000000

Comment: This is confusing... which one is Table_1 and which one is Table_2?  It's much easier if you just use the real table names from the start.  In my code above, I believe `usertable` = `table_1` = `Ip_relations_addresses`, and `geotable` = `table_2` = `postalcode`.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, but i myself had different examples for testing. In future i will use original names. Table 1 is lp_relations_addresses, so your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, and I may not have the syntax quite right, but this is the principle:

```
UPDATE table_1  COLUMNS(latitude, longitude) VALUES (
   SELECT latitude, longitude FROM table_2 
      where table_1.zip LIKE CONCAT(table_2.zip, ' %'));
```